# Unity: Knockback my player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity, direction

I have this script attached to an object, if my player encounters that object it will be knocked back. I have six directions on which it will be knocked back. This [image](http://noobtuts.com/content/unity/2d-pong-game/vector2_directions.png) will show you the different direction of which my player may get knock back. My problem: `X=0,Y=1` (up) and `X=0,Y=-1` (down) doesn't work, however every other velocity works. How can I also include the directions of X=0,Y=1 and X=0,Y=-1. Thank you and here is my code:

```
public class Knockback: MonoBehaviour
{
    public float xForceToAdd;
    public float yForceToAdd;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //Store the vector 2 of the location where the initial hit happened;
            Vector2 initialHitPoint = new Vector2(other.gameObject.transform.position.x, other.gameObject.transform.position.y);
            float xForce = 0;
            float yForce = 0;
            //Grab our collided with objects rigibody
            Rigidbody2D rigidForForce = other.gameObject.GetComponent < Rigidbody2D > ();
            //Determine left right center of X hit
            if (initialHitPoint.x > (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3)))
            {
                xForce = 1;
            }
            else if (initialHitPoint.x < (this.transform.position.x - (this.transform.localScale.x / 3)))
            {
                xForce = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                xForce = 0;
            }
            if (initialHitPoint.y > (this.transform.position.y + (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
            {
                yForce = 1;
            }
            else if (initialHitPoint.y < (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
            {
                yForce = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                yForce = 0;
            }
            rigidForForce.velocity = new Vector2(xForce * xForceToAdd, yForce * yForceToAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So left and right (where `Y=0`) both work I take it? Perhaps the problem is with whatever `localScale.x` is? Possibly it needs to be bigger.

Comment: Just to verify, do you mean there are eight directions that your player can be knocked back (as per the image and the intended code)?

Comment: Also, what version of Unity are you using?  I've found that some versions have difficulty with Vector2.  Even for 2D stuff, I tend to use Vector3 and keep the z-axis as 0.

It might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, it doesn't see the `if` statements of y part. Use `else if` for all `if` statements after the first one. Try this:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        //Store the vector 2 of the location where the initial hit happened;
        Vector2 initialHitPoint = new Vector2(other.gameObject.transform.position.x, other.gameObject.transform.position.y);
        float xForce = 0;
        float yForce = 0;
        //Grab our collided with objects rigibody
        Rigidbody2D rigidForForce = other.gameObject.GetComponent < Rigidbody2D > ();
        //Determine left right center of X hit
        if (initialHitPoint.x > (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3))
                && initialHitPoint.y > (this.transform.position.y + (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            xForce = 1;
            yForce = 1;
        }
        else if (initialHitPoint.x > (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3))
                && initialHitPoint.y < (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            xForce = 1;
            yForce = -1;
        }
        else if (initialHitPoint.x < (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3))
                && initialHitPoint.y > (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            xForce = -1;
            yForce = 1;
        }
        else if (initialHitPoint.x < (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3))
                && initialHitPoint.y < (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            xForce = -1;
            yForce = -1;
        }
        else if (initialHitPoint.x > (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3))
                && initialHitPoint.y == (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            xForce = 1;
            yForce = 0;
        }
        else if (initialHitPoint.x < (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3))
                && initialHitPoint.y == (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            xForce = -1;
            yForce = 0;
        }
        else if (initialHitPoint.x == (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3))
                && initialHitPoint.y < (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            xForce = 0;
            yForce = -1;
        }
        else if (initialHitPoint.x == (this.transform.position.x + (this.transform.localScale.x / 3))
                && initialHitPoint.y > (this.transform.position.y - (this.transform.localScale.y / 3)))
        {
            xForce = 0;
            yForce = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            xForce = 0;
            yForce = 0;
        }
        rigidForForce.velocity = new Vector2(xForce * xForceToAdd, yForce * yForceToAdd);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the first set of if/elseif/else statements is for x-axis, the second is for y-axis.  elseif and else statements are only necessary if they cannot ALSO be combined with the initial if statement.  There are many times you may not want elseif or else at all, and just a series of if statements.  In this case, his pair of if/elseif/else seem to make sense.

Comment: I just expand the original code, both are them give same result. Sometimes, compiler cannot recognize some if statements' order and it's better to try like this.

Comment: Um... try what? i'm kinda confuse on what you mean by expanding the original code, just how am I suppose to do that? Thank you

Comment: It gives same result with your if statements group. It's not a big deal, I just suggest another view for your if statements.